# htaccess - access only if 2 dashes exist

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current rewrite rule to find users is this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/users/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ /index.php?hook=admin&url=users&search=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/users/(.*)$ /index.php?hook=admin&url=users&search=$1 [NC]
```

I can find

@username test

@email email@yahoo.com

@id 123

but when i'm searching by id /admin/users/@id-**755**,
id is recognized as page

**I thought to access first Rewrite only if contains 2 dashes,**
something like that

RewriteRule ^admin/users/(.*)**([-{2}])**([0-9]+)$

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

@anubhava

so I can find by username, email or id

url.com/admin/users/@username-test

url.com/admin/users/@email-email@yahoo.com

or

url.com/admin/users/@id-**222** but here the id is recognized as page and we can have also pages like

```
                    ID-PAGE
                     | |
```

url.com/admin/users/@id-**222**-2 with page in url is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# don't execute further rules for real files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/users/(.*?-.*?)-([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?hook=admin&url=users&search=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^admin/users/(.+)$ /index.php?hook=admin&url=users&search=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: yup, but the first number is recognized as page

Comment: Provide more details. What URL did you enter and what number got recognized as `page` parameter?

Comment: So problem is with `url.com/admin/users/@id-222-2` URI?

Comment: When I opened `/admin/users/@id-222-2` URI with this rule in place I got `$_GET['page']` as `2`. Is it incorrect?

Comment: is you're right.. when u open /admin/users/@id-222-2 you'll receive $_GET['page'] as 2.

Comment: the problem is "/admin/users/@id-222"

Comment: What should be `page` value in `/admin/users/@id-222` I get `222`

Comment: page should'nt be specified in that link